# RANK against multiple columns (Teradata)

Tags: teradata

Q: Is there a way to qualify a single column, while ignoring the rest of the columns present in the final report output?

I had to move this question to Teradata-only conference, since there is a solution for SQL Server.

My final output format looks like (without ranking restriction) :

```
PRODUCT1  STATE1  CITY_A  20
PRODUCT2  STATE1  CITY_A  10
PRODUCT3  STATE1  CITY_A  25

PRODUCT1  STATE1  CITY_B  20
PRODUCT2  STATE1  CITY_B  10
PRODUCT3  STATE1  CITY_B  1

PRODUCT1  STATE2  CITY_C  20
PRODUCT2  STATE2  CITY_C  10
PRODUCT3  STATE2  CITY_C  1
```

I'm banging my head over a problem how to qualify highest 2 grossing PRODUCTs, *overall* produced by a dynamic SQL expression.

Desired output:

```
PRODUCT1  STATE1  CITY_A  20
PRODUCT2  STATE1  CITY_A  10

PRODUCT1  STATE1  CITY_B  20
PRODUCT2  STATE1  CITY_B  10

PRODUCT1  STATE2  CITY_C  20
PRODUCT2  STATE2  CITY_C  10
```

Product 3 should not qualify being RANKed <=2 - if ranked overall, and not being broken by state and city.
I'd like to see if an analytical function can be used at the external select level where the final formatted output is created.

Using Teradata 14.00, so no access to DENSE_RANK yet...

### UPDATE:

Mr.ZLK suggested a non-OLAP solution, which works in SQL Server, but not in TD, unfortunately:

```
select * from products sqlMain 
where product_id in (1,2,3) /* dynamic pre-condition */ 

    and product_id in 
    (select top 2 product_id from products t1 
       where sqlMain.product_id=t1.product_id 
     group by product_id order by sum(total) desc 
    )
```

This would give PRODUCT1 and PRODUCT2

```
select * from products sqlMain 
where product_id in (3) /* another dynamic pre-condition */ 

    and product_id in 
    (select top 2 product_id from products t1 
       where sqlMain.product_id=t1.product_id 
     group by product_id order by sum(total) desc 
    )
```

This would give PRODUCT3, correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that those SQL Server queries return the correct result? IMHO  those Correlated Subqueries don't change the result, you simply get all rows matching the 1st `WHERE product_id in (...)`

Comment: the subquery is ordered, so the first 2 values returned would be the highest-ranked; check out the where clause of the inline select

Comment: The Where-clause restrict the subquery to the scope of the outer product_id, there will never be more than a single id to be "ranked". This matches your description: `select * from products sqlMain 
where product_id in 
    (select top 2 product_id from products t1 
       product_id in (1,2,3) /* dynamic pre-condition */   
     group by product_id order by sum(total) desc 
    )`. When you switch to a join instead you can use it in Teradata, too (or use `QUALIFY RANK() OVER (order by sum(total) desc )<=2`)

Comment: I beg to differ. The sqlMain in the first example produces 3 product_ids, which are then joined in the outer where clause, preceding the top & order clauses - hence generating the product_id 1,2 response. In the second example only product_id 3 is fused, thus the outer SQL returns only one top value 3. Tested this in SQL Server. Can not do the same in Teradata, since it doesn't allow order and top in inline views. Will test your other proposal and post here, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your Teradata version is higher than 14.10, you could use the `DENSE_RANK` analytical function in a `QUALIFY` clause.

Assuming that the columns of your table are `product`, `state`, `city` and `gross`, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT
  product,
  state,
  city,
  gross
FROM (SELECT
        product,
        state,
        city,
        gross,
        SUM(gross) OVER(PARTITION BY product) AS total
      FROM yourTable) t
QUALIFY DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY total DESC) <= 2
;
```

Comment: I know! I'm on 14.00, bummer. For dense_rank I have to use a two-headed workaround, which, with a massive report SQL you need to embed twice, doesn't look like a neat solution. In my case, the "yourTable" is a 4-story-high SQL expression. But I'll try this as well..

Comment: Let us know if you find the way to do it! Maybe you should edit your question to include the Teradata version and other constraints for future helpers.